# Can't figure out how to do this all in one function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a zoo simulation game in Unity 5.4.0f3 using C#. I am trying to spawn a bear prefab clone, do some math, wait for a period of time, do some more math, then destroy the clone object all in one function. Here is what I have right now. The math that I am trying to do in WaitForBearLife() does not happen. Thanks in advance!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BuyBearButton : MonoBehaviour 
{
    [SerializeField] GameManager gameManager;
    [SerializeField] GameObject bearPrefab;
    [SerializeField] Visitor visitor;

    GameObject bearClone;

    float xMin = -15;
    float xMax = 15;
    float yMin = 5;
    float yMax = 6;

    public void BuyBear()
    {
        Vector2 pos = new Vector2 (Random.Range (xMin, xMax), Random.Range (yMin, yMax));

        if (gameManager.myMoney >= gameManager.bearCost) 
        {
            gameManager.numberOfBears++;
            gameManager.myMoney = gameManager.myMoney - gameManager.bearCost;
            visitor.spawnTime = visitor.spawnTime / visitor.bearAttraction;
            bearClone = (GameObject) Instantiate (bearPrefab, pos, transform.rotation);
            StartCoroutine (WaitForBearLife ());
            Destroy (bearClone, gameManager.bearLife);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator WaitForBearLife()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (gameManager.bearLife);
        visitor.spawnTime = visitor.spawnTime * visitor.bearAttraction;
    }
}
```

Comment: I look your code, i think you need move Destroy method after yield return. 

'IEnumerator WaitForBearLife()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (gameManager.bearLife);
        visitor.spawnTime = visitor.spawnTime * visitor.bearAttraction;
        Destroy (bearClone, gameManager.bearLife);
    }'

Comment: I tried that, but the bear clones don't get destroyed then AND the math doesn't get done. It's looks like WaitForBearLife() just isn't working at all.

Comment: Just use Destroy (bearClone) not any param :D

Comment: Ok, I just tried that and nothing changed. It still seems like the IEnumerator isn't doing anything. I have this script attached to a UI button that calls the function when clicked. Does that have any impact on this?

Comment: Are you playing that code in Play mode? Try to put log before and after the yield in your IEnumerator method to be sure it is launched.

Comment: I would suggest to take a look at [ask] as I think your title doesn't really summarize your problem very well. It seems to be your problem is more about a coroutine you can't get to run. Your question also doesn't show much research effort. Have you looked at similar questions about coroutines? I get 1552 results if I search "[unity3d] StartCoroutine" on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bunity3d%5D+StartCoroutine. Are really none of them useful for you to get to a solution you need?

Comment: There are also other places to ask this sort of question or to search for a solution to your problem. For example http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ and [the Unity Community](https://unity3d.com/community). Have you tried to search for a solution there too?

Answer (score 1):

you need to move Destroy function from BuyBear to WaitForBearLife

The problem is that now StartCouroutine call immediately returns and Destroy() gets called right away

Answer (score 0):

I've just copied your code in an empty project, and made placeholder classes for GameManager and Visitor, just with random values in the variables we need in this script. It works just fine... really.So, I'll make you some questions (as I don't have the reputation yet to comment in your post...)

**First, there's a script in the bear prefab of any sorts?**

This is because it *maybe* have something that could interrupt the coroutine. It seems unlikely, but you can't know for sure until you try.

**Next, how is the declaration of Visitor and GameManager?**

The very beginning, when you define the class name and such. In fact, I would like to know more about the variables you used, like gameManager.bearLife and such.

**Now, let's see the values.**

I've tried with:

```
public int myMoney = 50000;
public int bearCost = 50;
public int numberOfBears = 0;
public float bearLife = 2.0f;
```

In GameManager. And:

```
public float spawnTime = 5;
public float bearAttraction = 2;
```

In Visitor. It does some weird math, and the logic of this script itself is clearly in development right now, I suppose. But the point is, it works, and with this:

```
IEnumerator WaitForBearLife()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (gameManager.bearLife);
    print (visitor.spawnTime);
    visitor.spawnTime = visitor.spawnTime * visitor.bearAttraction;
    print (visitor.spawnTime);
}
```

I get 2.5 and 5 in the correspondant prints if I only click **once**. Some prints (As @Benjamin-lecomte stated) could help you to know if it's even executing that part.

For now, I can't help you without knowing much more. So I'll wait for your answer, then.